# parseInt returns NaN for second element whereas Number works perfectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, nan, parseint

Consider this extract from a function for squaring every digit:

```js
const result = num.toString().split('').map(Number).map(n => n * n);
```

In this when I use `parseInt` in the `map()` instead of `Number`, the second element in the array (with index 1) always gets the value `NaN` but `Number` works perfectly fine. I read the docs but still didn't get it. Can anyone tell why this happens?

Comment: `map` passes the index as the second parameter of `parseInt`, but you can skip the first map as `*` will coerce to number anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, that's why I made the comment :)